# Passing URL in selenium without http or https

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check whether the URL's are https or not?

For this:
I need to pass URL's without http/https.
eg: `driver.get("google.com");` and `driver.get("http://google.com");`

Can anyone help me out please. Is it possible to automate such scenario's ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`driver.get()` requires valid URL that starts with "http"/"https". However, `driver.get("http://www.google.com")` will navigate to "https://www.google.com"

For the parsing you can use `startsWith` method

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
if (url.startsWith("https")) {
    // url is https
}
else {
    // url is http
}
```

Comment: My question is firstly I want to open URL in selenium webdriver without any authentication as just driver.get("google.com"). And I tried giving driver.get("google.com"); this has thrown an error saying "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function"

Comment: @naazneen3264 Try `driver.get("http://www.google.com");` It will navigate to https, but you need to give valid url.

Comment: Ya am able to use with "http" . But I wanted to pass without http/https.  So, is it possible ?

Comment: @naazneen3264 No, `driver.get()` requires valid url that starts with http/https