# How to check status of a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

How can I check the status of a website that the website is open or not. from not I mean sometime the url is changed for a website so nothing found in that or any other reason the url is not avalible. is there a way to check it.

```
driver.getCurrentUrl
```

I found this in a question but it's not helping **[Passing URL in selenium without http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986816/passing-url-in-selenium-without-http-or-https)**

Comment: Check the ResponseCode of the website through code, if it returns '404' then the website is not found or URL is wrong, if it is returns '200', then website is OK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.